# Import related errors- express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, mern

I am trying to use "module" type javascript with express-js first time. I am trying to create a book tracking application, but I am getting some error when I try to import routes in the main js file, it says cannot find module.

**Directory structure:**
[image]

**app.js:**

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// import routes
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth";

// db config
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
// constants
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// using routes
app.use("/api", authRoutes);

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}/`)
);
```

**routes/auth.js:**

```js
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from auth");
});

export default router;
```

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.5"
  }
}
```

**error:**
[image]

> Note: Other imports related to database models are all working fine!

Comment: delete node_module and try reinstalling using npm install in same directory as your app.js

Comment: I am not able to import from a localfile, other package imports are working perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add js extension Node ESM does not work without it

```
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
```